# Stored Procedure Delete query does not work. But when run in editor by itself and not called it works properly

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I wrote this stored procedure using SQL Server Management Studio.

If I execute it in the editor and manually assign a formname and a user ID it works properly cleaning up the settings that don't match anything

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Handover_DeleteBadParams] 
     @UserID varchar(10), 
     @formName varchar (30)
as
begin
   with deletethese as
   (     
       select 
           UserID, Param 
       from
           BI.dbo.Handover_RDL_SavedSettings userSettings
       left join
           BI.dbo.Handover_UI form on Form.FormName = userSettings.FormName 
                                   and userSettings.Param = Form.ItemValue
       where 
          userSettings.FormName = @UserID
          and userSettings.UserID = @formName
          and Form.FormName IS NULL)
   Delete from S
   from bi.dbo.Handover_RDL_SavedSettings S
   join deletethese D on S.UserId = D.UserID and S.Param = D.Param;
end
```

Then I call the stored procedure using C#

```
using (SqlCommand kill = new SqlCommand("Handover_DeleteBadParams",cc))
{
    kill.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    kill.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userID;
    kill.Parameters.Add("@formName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = working_form_name;

    kill.Connection.Open();
    kill.ExecuteNonQuery();
    kill.Connection.Close();
}
```

I get no errors or any sort of feedback during execution....   What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you run sql profiler and make sure it runs with the expected Params

Comment: Is the database user the same in both cases? If not, may be a permissions issue.

Comment: The first thing I'd check is the SqlConnection object.  I think that's `cc` in your SqlCommand constructor, right?  Put a break point there, take a look at `cc` and verify it's connecting to the SQL instance and database it should be.

Comment: Data base admins get mad when we run traces.

User is Different in each case.  

I use CC other places in the code the same way.. I would expect an exception if something happened there. 

Thanks for all of the comments and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem I note is in your stored procedure you appear to have your parameters reversed:

```
 where userSettings.FormName = @UserID
 and userSettings.UserID = @formName
```

should probably be

```
 where userSettings.FormName =  @formName
 and userSettings.UserID = @UserID
```

Comment: Dunno how I missed that.  Thanks... seems to be working properly now.  I was spending time re-inventing the wheel.  Sometimes just need other people to look at it and see what you missed.  Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since it executes without any errors, but simply doesn't delete anything, we must conclude your `userID` and/or `working_form_name` don't contain the values you think they do.

Set a breakpoint in the C# just before the call, and check the values to verify that this is the problem.

Comment: Setup a message box they did indeed contain what was needed but were being used against the wrong fields.  Great suggestion though.